# Why I'm getting this kind of error? illegal character

Tags: java

Do someone have anyone of you met this problem before?

I created simply for loop, which is creating 3 types of object and when I'm trying run it im getting errors.

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Object> listObiektow= new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0; i < 1000; i++){
        listObiektow.add(new Czołg("Czołg", 500, 100, 50, 10, 100, 100, 500))
    {
        });
    }

}
```

---

```
public class Statek {

    private String name;
    private int hp;
    private int armor;
    private int dmg;
    private int speed;
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int hpLeft;

    public Statek(String name, int hp, int armor, int dmg, int speed, int x, int y, int hpLeft) {
        this.name = name;
        this.hp = hp;
        this.armor = armor;
        this.dmg = dmg;
        this.speed = speed;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.hpLeft = hpLeft;
    }
```

> Task :compileJava FAILED
>   C:\Users\Szymon\Desktop\WzorzecProjektowyPy�ek\src\main\java\Jednostki\Czo�g.java:3: error: illegal character: '\u201a'
>   public class Czołg {
>                    ^
>   C:\Users\Szymon\Desktop\WzorzecProjektowyPy�ek\src\main\java\Jednostki\Czo�g.java:14: error: illegal character: '\u201a'
>       public Czołg(String name, int hp, int armor, int dmg, int speed, int x, int y, int hpLeft) {
>                  ^
>   C:\Users\Szymon\Desktop\WzorzecProjektowyPy�ek\src\main\java\Jednostki\Czo�g.java:14: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
>       public Czołg(String name, int hp, int armor, int dmg, int speed, int x, int y, int hpLeft) {
>                   ^
>   C:\Users\Szymon\Desktop\WzorzecProjektowyPy�ek\src\main\java\Main.java:1: error: illegal character: '\u201a'
>   import Jednostki.Czołg;
>                        ^
>   C:\Users\Szymon\Desktop\WzorzecProjektowyPy�ek\src\main\java\Main.java:14: error: illegal character: '\u201a'
>               listObiektow.add(new Czołg("Czołg", 500, 100, 50, 10, 100, 100, 500));
>                                        ^
>   C:\Users\Szymon\Desktop\WzorzecProjektowyPy�ek\src\main\java\Main.java:14: error: ';' expected
>               listObiektow.add(new Czołg("Czołg", 500, 100, 50, 10, 100, 100, 500));
>                                         ^
>   C:\Users\Szymon\Desktop\WzorzecProjektowyPy�ek\src\main\java\Main.java:14: error: ')' expected
>               listObiektow.add(new Czołg("Czołg", 500, 100, 50, 10, 100, 100, 500));
>                                                   ^
>   C:\Users\Szymon\Desktop\WzorzecProjektowyPy�ek\src\main\java\Main.java:14: error: not a statement
>               listObiektow.add(new Czołg("Czołg", 500, 100, 50, 10, 100, 100, 500));
>                                          ^
>   C:\Users\Szymon\Desktop\WzorzecProjektowyPy�ek\src\main\java\Main.java:14: error: not a statement
>               listObiektow.add(new Czołg("Czołg", 500, 100, 50, 10, 100, 100, 500));
>                                                     ^
>   C:\Users\Szymon\Desktop\WzorzecProjektowyPy�ek\src\main\java\Main.java:14: error: ';' expected
>               listObiektow.add(new Czołg("Czołg", 500, 100, 50, 10, 100, 100, 500));
>                                                        ^
>   10 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.

  > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: What if you renamed `Czołg` to something that has letters from the English dictionary (A-Z, a-z)?

Comment: can you show code for Czołg class?

Comment: Use ASCII characters for identifiers and such. `new Czołg` *could* be compiled with the right encoding (I think), but should be avoided. Rename your class to  `Czolg` and it should work.

Comment: Ahh... The solution was so simple... The problem was with polish characters. " Ł" inside "Czołg" word created these problem. Many thanks guys!

Comment: Well yea ... but you should be able to make it work.  I suspect that you need to tell the javac compiler to use the appropriate source code encoding to use; see `man javac` and look the `-encoding` option.   Or ... since you are using a build tool ... figure out how to specify the correct source file encoding in the build file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is with the word "Czołg"

Rename / Refactor to Czolg and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Change encoding of file on UTF-8

Comment: How do you know the file is encoded in UTF-8, and not something like ISO-8859-2 or windows-1250?